# Android: Unable to add window. Permission denied for this window type

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I'm working on an app where I need to display a window with some info **ON** the Lock Screen (KeyGuard) without unlocking the phone. I figured I could probably do it with [WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG)

But every time my app crashes with the following error:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@40ec8528 -- permission denied for this
>   window type

These posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569937/unable-to-add-window-android-view-viewrootw44da9bc0-permission-denied-for-t), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400539/windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103401/windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-android-view-viewrootw4)) all give the same answer.
To add the following permission in the Manifest file.

> android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Solution that I have implemented but I am still getting the same error.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Here are the permissions in my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.droidpilot.keyguardwindow" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

And this is the code I use to add the Window to the lock screen

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lock_screen_notif, null);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );

    wm.addView(mView, params);
```

Anybody got any idea?

P.S. I'm testing on an HTC Desire 620 DS running Android 4.4.2

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For what should be completely obvious reasons, **ordinary Apps are not allowed to create arbitrary windows on top of the lock screen**. What do you think I could do if I created a window on your lockscreen that could perfectly imitate the real lockscreen so you couldn't tell the difference?

The technical reason for your error is the use of the `TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG` flag - it requires `android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW` which is a signature-level permission. This means that only Apps signed with the *same certificate* as the creator of the permission can use it.

The creator of `android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW` is the Android system itself, so unless your App is part of the OS, you don't stand a chance.

There are well defined and well documented ways of [notifying the user of information from the lockscreen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#lockscreenNotification). You can create customised notifications which show on the lockscreen and the user can interact with them.

Comment: Personally I was looking for something like the lock screen notifications of the Facebook app. I already knew about the new lock screen notifications but these only work in Android 22 for now. I need a solution that would work on Android 16 and up. But your answer makes perfect sense and I will accept it as such. 

I did manage to display a window on the lock screen though but its not what I need, I will post the solution I found below.

Comment: If apps need that permission it could be granted after it is installed and opened.

Comment: I think that since Oreo this is the right answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481628/504179

Answer (score 115):

if you use `apiLevel >= 19`, don't use

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT
```

which gets the following error:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@40ec8528 -- permission denied for this window type

Use this instead:

```
LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST or TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL
```

Comment: I've got `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` working fine on Android 5.1 with the `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` granted in the manifest.

Comment: I have to use `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` with  `LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST`?

Comment: I tried LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST . Its working for me on Lollipop and Marshmallow both API level 6.0.1. Before that I was using WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT , which was working only for Lollipop .

Comment: unfortunately it cause “Screen overlay detected” in case some application requests permission dialog (if your view active)

Comment: This would not work if you are trying to show the window from within a service or broadcast receiver

Comment: How can I replace my WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR?

Answer (score 89):

I guess you should differentiate the target (before and after Oreo)

```
int LAYOUT_FLAG;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
} else {
    LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
}

params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LAYOUT_FLAG,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: I'm trying to use a similar technique but android studio is unable to recognize `Build.VERSION_CODES.O` & `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`. My targetSdkVersion is 26

Comment: Appreciate your help +1 from my side.

Comment: @GabeO'Leary I am facing same issue ,do you have solution for this ?

Answer (score 55):

I tried my best to try all the examples available for this issue. Finally I got the answer for this I don know how much is it reliable but my app is not crashing now.

```
windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    //here is all the science of params
    final LayoutParams myParams = new LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );
```

In your manifest file just give the permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Addition to this you can also check for the API level if its >=23 then

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(Activity.this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
    }
}
            else
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, Service.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

I hope it helps someone somewhere.
Full example
https://anam-android-codes.blogspot.in/?m=1

Answer (score 17):

For Android API level of 8.0.0, you should use

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
```

instead of

```
LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST or TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL
```

or `SYSTEM_ALERT`.

Comment: TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY is not in the list of options presented in Android Studio. I get "cannot resolve symbol type". What am I missing?

Answer (score 13):

try this code working perfectly

```
int layout_parms;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) 

    {  
         layout_parms = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;

    }

     else {

            layout_parms = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;

    }

    yourparams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(       
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            layout_parms,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Comment: you saved my life

Comment: @BakaWaii where you want to show widget to put this code in there will work fine

Answer (score 8):

Search

> Draw over other apps

in your setting and enable your app.
For Android 8 Oreo, try

> Settings > Apps & Notifications > App info > Display over other apps >
>   Enable

Comment: you are a lifesaver

Answer (score 7):

Firstly you make sure you have add permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Check if the application has draw over other apps permission or not?
This permission is by default available for API<23. But for API > 23 you have to ask for the permission in runtime.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
            Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Use This code:

```
public class ChatHeadService extends Service {

private WindowManager mWindowManager;
private View mChatHeadView;

WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

public ChatHeadService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Language language = new Language();
    //Inflate the chat head layout we created
    mChatHeadView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_incoming_call, null);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mWindowManager.addView(mChatHeadView, params);

    } else {
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mWindowManager.addView(mChatHeadView, params);
    }

    TextView tvTitle=mChatHeadView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    tvTitle.setText("Incoming Call");

    //Set the close button.
    Button btnReject = (Button) mChatHeadView.findViewById(R.id.btnReject);
    btnReject.setText(language.getText(R.string.reject));
    btnReject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //close the service and remove the chat head from the window
            stopSelf();
        }
    });

    //Drag and move chat head using user's touch action.
    final Button btnAccept = (Button) mChatHeadView.findViewById(R.id.btnAccept);
    btnAccept.setText(language.getText(R.string.accept));


    LinearLayout linearLayoutMain=mChatHeadView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutMain);



    linearLayoutMain.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int lastAction;
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    //remember the initial position.
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;

                    //get the touch location
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();

                    lastAction = event.getAction();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //As we implemented on touch listener with ACTION_MOVE,
                    //we have to check if the previous action was ACTION_DOWN
                    //to identify if the user clicked the view or not.
                    if (lastAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        //Open the chat conversation click.
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ChatHeadService.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        //close the service and remove the chat heads
                        stopSelf();
                    }
                    lastAction = event.getAction();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //Calculate the X and Y coordinates of the view.
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);

                    //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mChatHeadView, params);
                    lastAction = event.getAction();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mChatHeadView != null) mWindowManager.removeView(mChatHeadView);
}
```

}

Comment: can you share your xml code and view in github or something else it will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 6):

I just added simple view to `WindowManager` with the following steps:

1. Create one layout file to show(dummy_layout in my case)
2. Add permission in manifest and dynamically.

```java
// 1. Show view
private void showCustomPopupMenu()
{
    windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    // LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    // View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_layout, null);
    ViewGroup valetModeWindow = (ViewGroup) View.inflate(this, R.layout.dummy_layout, null);
    int LAYOUT_FLAG;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
    } else {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
    }
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params=new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LAYOUT_FLAG,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity= Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER;
    params.x=0;
    params.y=0;
    windowManager.addView(valetModeWindow, params);
}

// 2. Get permissions by asking
if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
}
```

With this you can add a view to WM.

Tested in Pie.

Comment: i have use this code but when open settings phone this popup hide ? why? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

change your flag Windowmanger flag "TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY" to "TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY" in your project to make compatible with Android O

`WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE` to `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`

Comment: Still the same error

Answer (score 3):

I did manage to finally display a window on the lock screen with the use of `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` instead of `TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG`. This works as expected and adds the window on the lock screen.

The problem with this is that the window is added **on top of everything it possibly can.** That is, the window will even appear on top of your keypad/pattern lock in case of secure lock screens. In the case of an unsecured lock screen, it will appear on top of the notification tray if you open it from the lock screen.

For me, that is unacceptable. I hope that this may help anybody else facing this problem.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the solution. Is there a way to dismiss it? I'm not able to dismiss the dialog when I add it as `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`. My setOnDismissListener on AlertDialog is not getting invoked.

Answer (score 2):

LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE is deprecated. I have updated my code like these.

```
parameters = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 25) {
        LayoutParams(
                minHW * 2 / 3, minHW * 2 / 3,
                LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
    }else {
        LayoutParams(
                minHW * 2 / 3, minHW * 2 / 3,
                LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
    }
```

LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY requires api level 26 or above.

Answer (score 1):

The Main Reason for the denying permission is that we don’t have permission for drawing over another apps,We have to provide the permission for the Drawing over other apps that can be done by the following code

Request code for Permission

```java
    public static int ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 5469;
```

add this in your **MainActivity**

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            askPermission();
}
```

```java
private void askPermission() {
        Intent intent= new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:"+getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent,ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Add this also

```java
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)){
                askPermission();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to find the working solution with `ApplicationContext` and `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` and found confusing solutions, In case you want the dialog should be opened from any activity even the dialog is a singleton you have to use `getApplicationContext()`, and if want the dialog should be `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` you will need the following steps:

first get the instance of dialog with correct theme, also you need to manage the version compatibility as I did in my following snippet:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light);
```

After setting the title, message and buttons you have to build the dialog as:

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Now the `type` plays the main roll here, since this is the reason of crash, I handled the compatibility as following:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY - 1);

    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    }
```

**Note**: if you are using a custom dialog with `AppCompatDialog` as below:

```
AppCompatDialog dialog = new AppCompatDialog(getApplicationContext(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light);
```

you can directly define your type to the `AppCompatDialog` instance as following:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY - 1);

    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    }
```

Don't forget to add the manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
    params.x = left;
    params.y = top;
    windowManager.addView(view, params);

} else {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);


    params.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
    params.x = left;
    params.y = top;
    windowManager.addView(view, params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` is added for OS version < Oreo as it's been deprecated.