# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@3decac7 -- permission denied for this window type

Tags: android, overlay, android-windowmanager

I have an windows manager inside the broadcast receiver and am using API > 23 so i provided overlay permission in the main activity like below.

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

After providing the permission also am getting the below error .

```
 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@3decac7 -- permission denied for this window type.
```

window manager used in the broadcast receiver

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new 
 WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
                            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
                    params.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;
                    params.x=0;
                    params.y=0;
                    windowManager.addView(look, params);
```

provided permissionin Manifest also.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

please help how to proceed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224452/android-unable-to-add-window-permission-denied-for-this-window-type

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya - tried the above solution but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad layout type ( `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_DIALOG`).
You can use `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` for api >= 26 and `TYPE_TOAST` for lower api.
Also you can read the WindowManager.LayoutParams api doc to know wich type you can use