# Permission denied for window type 2002 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-permissions

Today I installed latest version of Android Studio

I am learning Floating Widgets in Android

I started with applying this example

https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/android-floating-widget-tutorial/

it compiles ok

but when I run it in the emulator it crashes

giving me this error

```
08-28 22:52:02.932 7400-7400/com.asmgx.MyApp.MyApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.asmgx.MyApp.MyApp, PID: 7400
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.asmgx.MyApp.MyApp.FloatWidgetService: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@7c93828 -- permission denied for window type 2002
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3544)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@7c93828 -- permission denied for window type 2002
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:822)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
        at com.asmgx.MyApp.MyApp.FloatWidgetService.onCreate(FloatWidgetService.java:36)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3532)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I tried resolving the issue and found this link

[Unable to add window android.view.ViewRoot$W@44da9bc0 -- permission denied for this window type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569937/unable-to-add-window-android-view-viewrootw44da9bc0-permission-denied-for-t)

they suggested adding this line to the manifest, which already added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

anyone know why am i getting this?

PS. I used emulator with Android 28 and another with android 27

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is occurring because the targetSdkVersion in the example and your targetSdkVersion are different. Use the flag TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY instead of TYPE_PHONE in WindowManager.LayoutParams:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
```

Comment: how can i experiment with different flags ?

Comment: Try different flags like overlay

Comment: Try  the following flags:
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY,

Comment: It crashes on all other types. is there any other way i can get it working?

Comment: TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY ?

Comment: Works :) Thanks heaps

Comment: `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` has been added in API 26 not 22
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams

Comment: You've misinterpreted the answer. Either downgrade the targetSdkVersion to 22 or keep it at 26 and change the flag to TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY. Makes sense?

Comment: I downgraded because this accepted answer is not clear enough, option to downgrade targetSdkVersion 22 is not good solution is this mostly you don't want to do, there should be different flags for different versions as is proposed in other answers.

Comment: Downgrading the targetSDK verison is not a solution anymore and it is mandated by Google to have the latest version. Edited the answer to reflect that. Nevertheless, changing the flags like it was suggested in the answer should work

Comment: `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY ` gave me `permission denied for window type 2038` on Android 10 and 11. `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` has been requested in the manifest file.

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me.. I'm sure it can be simplified, but it works perfectly otherwise.
Simply replace `TYPE_PHONE` with `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` if (and *only* if) user is equal or above Oreo:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    } else {
        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    }
```

OR do this in simple way

```
    int LAYOUT_FLAG;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        } else {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
        }

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LAYOUT_FLAG,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Answer (score 4):

By changing targetSdkVersion to  22, the issue will be solved partially. For devices above 22 you will get the same error.
I found the following answer in stack overflow but didn't remember the link. You can try the following code:

```
private void createFloatView() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkDrawOverlayPermission();
    } else {
        createView();
    }
}

public void checkDrawOverlayPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(getContext())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getActivity().getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, CommonVariables.REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            createView();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CommonVariables.REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(getContext())) {
                createView();
            }
        }
    }
}

 private int CommonVariables.REQUEST_CODE = 5463 & 0xffffff00
```

Comment: This is your missing link.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224452/android-unable-to-add-window-permission-denied-for-this-window-type/47103959#47103959

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace

```
TYPE_PHONE,
```

in your code with

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O ? TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY : TYPE_PHONE,
```