# why in android mobile version 8.1 [oreo] the Floating Widget service is not working? [app is getting crushed]

Tags: android, widget, floating

I was working in Floating Widget service icon ,the code is working fine till android version 6.1,i am able to get the notification icon from the server when it send the notification.

but while testing it in android version 8.1 the application getting crushed when the notification is send from the server,
but i am not able to find the solution for it.i dont have any idea why it is happening.

LOGCAT

```
 beginning of crash
2019-03-02 11:41:21.416 12616-12616/com.progressive_solution.parttimeforce E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.progressive_solution.parttimeforce, PID: 12616
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.progressive_solution.parttimeforce.FloatingWidgetService: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@ac5309 -- permission denied for window type 2002
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3568)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1812)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
     Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@ac5309 -- permission denied for window type 2002
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:1026)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:384)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:101)
        at com.progressive_solution.parttimeforce.FloatingWidgetService.addRemoveView(FloatingWidgetService.java:86)
        at com.progressive_solution.parttimeforce.FloatingWidgetService.onCreate(FloatingWidgetService.java:58)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3558)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1812) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

MYCODE

FloatingWidgetService.java

```
public class FloatingWidgetService extends Service implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private View mFloatingWidgetView, collapsedView, expandedView;
    private ImageView remove_image_view;
    private Point szWindow = new Point();
    private View removeFloatingWidgetView;

    private int x_init_cord, y_init_cord, x_init_margin, y_init_margin;

    //Variable to check if the Floating widget view is on left side or in right side
    // initially we are displaying Floating widget view to Left side so set it to true
    private boolean isLeft = true;

    public FloatingWidgetService() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //init WindowManager
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        getWindowManagerDefaultDisplay();

        //Init LayoutInflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        addRemoveView(inflater);
        addFloatingWidgetView(inflater);
        implementClickListeners();
        implementTouchListenerToFloatingWidgetView();
    }


    /*  Add Remove View to Window Manager  */
    private View addRemoveView(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        //Inflate the removing view layout we created
        removeFloatingWidgetView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remove_floating_widget_layout, null);

        //Add the view to the window.
        WindowManager.LayoutParams paramRemove = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        //Specify the view position
        paramRemove.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

        //Initially the Removing widget view is not visible, so set visibility to GONE
        removeFloatingWidgetView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        remove_image_view = (ImageView) removeFloatingWidgetView.findViewById(R.id.remove_img);

        //Add the view to the window
        mWindowManager.addView(removeFloatingWidgetView, paramRemove);
        return remove_image_view;
    }

    /*  Add Floating Widget View to Window Manager  */
    private void addFloatingWidgetView(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        //Inflate the floating view layout we created
        mFloatingWidgetView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_floating_widget_service, null);

        //Add the view to the window.
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        //Specify the view position
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

        //Initially view will be added to top-left corner, you change x-y coordinates according to your need
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        //Add the view to the window
        mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingWidgetView, params);

        //find id of collapsed view layout
        collapsedView = mFloatingWidgetView.findViewById(R.id.collapse_view);

        //find id of the expanded view layout
        expandedView = mFloatingWidgetView.findViewById(R.id.expanded_container);
    }

    private void getWindowManagerDefaultDisplay() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
            mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(szWindow);
        else {
            int w = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            int h = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
            szWindow.set(w, h);
        }
    }

    /*  Implement Touch Listener to Floating Widget Root View  */
    private void implementTouchListenerToFloatingWidgetView() {
        //Drag and move floating view using user's touch action.
        mFloatingWidgetView.findViewById(R.id.root_container).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            long time_start = 0, time_end = 0;

            boolean isLongClick = false;//variable to judge if user click long press
            boolean inBounded = false;//variable to judge if floating view is bounded to remove view
            int remove_img_width = 0, remove_img_height = 0;

            Handler handler_longClick = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable_longClick = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //On Floating Widget Long Click

                    //Set isLongClick as true
                    isLongClick = true;

                    //Set remove widget view visibility to VISIBLE
                    removeFloatingWidgetView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    onFloatingWidgetLongClick();
                }
            };

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                //Get Floating widget view params
                WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) mFloatingWidgetView.getLayoutParams();

                //get the touch location coordinates
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                int x_cord_Destination, y_cord_Destination;

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        handler_longClick.postDelayed(runnable_longClick, 600);

                        remove_img_width = remove_image_view.getLayoutParams().width;
                        remove_img_height = remove_image_view.getLayoutParams().height;

                        x_init_cord = x_cord;
                        y_init_cord = y_cord;

                        //remember the initial position.
                        x_init_margin = layoutParams.x;
                        y_init_margin = layoutParams.y;

                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        isLongClick = false;
                        removeFloatingWidgetView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        remove_image_view.getLayoutParams().height = remove_img_height;
                        remove_image_view.getLayoutParams().width = remove_img_width;
                        handler_longClick.removeCallbacks(runnable_longClick);

                        //If user drag and drop the floating widget view into remove view then stop the service
                        if (inBounded) {
                            stopSelf();
                            inBounded = false;
                            break;
                        }


                        //Get the difference between initial coordinate and current coordinate
                        int x_diff = x_cord - x_init_cord;
                        int y_diff = y_cord - y_init_cord;

                        //The check for x_diff <5 && y_diff< 5 because sometime elements moves a little while clicking.
                        //So that is click event.
                        if (Math.abs(x_diff) < 5 && Math.abs(y_diff) < 5) {
                            time_end = System.currentTimeMillis();

                            //Also check the difference between start time and end time should be less than 300ms
                            if ((time_end - time_start) < 300)
                                onFloatingWidgetClick();

                        }

                        y_cord_Destination = y_init_margin + y_diff;

                        int barHeight = getStatusBarHeight();
                        if (y_cord_Destination < 0) {
                            y_cord_Destination = 0;
                        } else if (y_cord_Destination + (mFloatingWidgetView.getHeight() + barHeight) > szWindow.y) {
                            y_cord_Destination = szWindow.y - (mFloatingWidgetView.getHeight() + barHeight);
                        }

                        layoutParams.y = y_cord_Destination;

                        inBounded = false;

                        //reset position if user drags the floating view
                        resetPosition(x_cord);

                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int x_diff_move = x_cord - x_init_cord;
                        int y_diff_move = y_cord - y_init_cord;

                        x_cord_Destination = x_init_margin + x_diff_move;
                        y_cord_Destination = y_init_margin + y_diff_move;

                        //If user long click the floating view, update remove view
                        if (isLongClick) {
                            int x_bound_left = szWindow.x / 2 - (int) (remove_img_width * 1.5);
                            int x_bound_right = szWindow.x / 2 + (int) (remove_img_width * 1.5);
                            int y_bound_top = szWindow.y - (int) (remove_img_height * 1.5);

                            //If Floating view comes under Remove View update Window Manager
                            if ((x_cord >= x_bound_left && x_cord <= x_bound_right) && y_cord >= y_bound_top) {
                                inBounded = true;

                                int x_cord_remove = (int) ((szWindow.x - (remove_img_height * 1.5)) / 2);
                                int y_cord_remove = (int) (szWindow.y - ((remove_img_width * 1.5) + getStatusBarHeight()));

                                if (remove_image_view.getLayoutParams().height == remove_img_height) {
                                    remove_image_view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (remove_img_height * 1.5);
                                    remove_image_view.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (remove_img_width * 1.5);

                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams param_remove = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) removeFloatingWidgetView.getLayoutParams();
                                    param_remove.x = x_cord_remove;
                                    param_remove.y = y_cord_remove;

                                    mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(removeFloatingWidgetView, param_remove);
                                }

                                layoutParams.x = x_cord_remove + (Math.abs(removeFloatingWidgetView.getWidth() - mFloatingWidgetView.getWidth())) / 2;
                                layoutParams.y = y_cord_remove + (Math.abs(removeFloatingWidgetView.getHeight() - mFloatingWidgetView.getHeight())) / 2;

                                //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                                mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingWidgetView, layoutParams);
                                break;
                            } else {
                                //If Floating window gets out of the Remove view update Remove view again
                                inBounded = false;
                                remove_image_view.getLayoutParams().height = remove_img_height;
                                remove_image_view.getLayoutParams().width = remove_img_width;
                                onFloatingWidgetClick();
                            }

                        }


                        layoutParams.x = x_cord_Destination;
                        layoutParams.y = y_cord_Destination;

                        //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingWidgetView, layoutParams);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void implementClickListeners() {
        mFloatingWidgetView.findViewById(R.id.close_floating_view).setOnClickListener(this);
        mFloatingWidgetView.findViewById(R.id.close_expanded_view).setOnClickListener(this);
        mFloatingWidgetView.findViewById(R.id.open_activity_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.close_floating_view:
                //close the service and remove the from from the window
                stopSelf();
                break;
            case R.id.close_expanded_view:
                collapsedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                expandedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case R.id.open_activity_button:
                //open the activity and stop service
                Intent intent = new Intent(FloatingWidgetService.this, Get_Permission.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

                //close the service and remove view from the view hierarchy
                stopSelf();
                break;
        }
    }

    /*  on Floating Widget Long Click, increase the size of remove view as it look like taking focus */
    private void onFloatingWidgetLongClick() {
        //Get remove Floating view params
        WindowManager.LayoutParams removeParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) removeFloatingWidgetView.getLayoutParams();

        //get x and y coordinates of remove view
        int x_cord = (szWindow.x - removeFloatingWidgetView.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y_cord = szWindow.y - (removeFloatingWidgetView.getHeight() + getStatusBarHeight());


        removeParams.x = x_cord;
        removeParams.y = y_cord;

        //Update Remove view params
        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(removeFloatingWidgetView, removeParams);
    }

    /*  Reset position of Floating Widget view on dragging  */
    private void resetPosition(int x_cord_now) {
        if (x_cord_now <= szWindow.x / 2) {
            isLeft = true;
            moveToLeft(x_cord_now);
        } else {
            isLeft = false;
            moveToRight(x_cord_now);
        }

    }


    /*  Method to move the Floating widget view to Left  */
    private void moveToLeft(final int current_x_cord) {
        final int x = szWindow.x - current_x_cord;

        new CountDownTimer(500, 5) {
            //get params of Floating Widget view
            WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) mFloatingWidgetView.getLayoutParams();

            public void onTick(long t) {
                long step = (500 - t) / 5;

                mParams.x = 0 - (int) (current_x_cord * current_x_cord * step);

                //If you want bounce effect uncomment below line and comment above line
                // mParams.x = 0 - (int) (double) bounceValue(step, x);


                //Update window manager for Floating Widget
                mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingWidgetView, mParams);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                mParams.x = 0;

                //Update window manager for Floating Widget
                mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingWidgetView, mParams);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    /*  Method to move the Floating widget view to Right  */
    private void moveToRight(final int current_x_cord) {

        new CountDownTimer(500, 5) {
            //get params of Floating Widget view
            WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) mFloatingWidgetView.getLayoutParams();

            public void onTick(long t) {
                long step = (500 - t) / 5;

                mParams.x = (int) (szWindow.x + (current_x_cord * current_x_cord * step) - mFloatingWidgetView.getWidth());

                //If you want bounce effect uncomment below line and comment above line
                //  mParams.x = szWindow.x + (int) (double) bounceValue(step, x_cord_now) - mFloatingWidgetView.getWidth();

                //Update window manager for Floating Widget
                mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingWidgetView, mParams);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                mParams.x = szWindow.x - mFloatingWidgetView.getWidth();

                //Update window manager for Floating Widget
                mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingWidgetView, mParams);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    /*  Get Bounce value if you want to make bounce effect to your Floating Widget */
    private double bounceValue(long step, long scale) {
        double value = scale * java.lang.Math.exp(-0.055 * step) * java.lang.Math.cos(0.08 * step);
        return value;
    }


    /*  Detect if the floating view is collapsed or expanded */
    private boolean isViewCollapsed() {
        return mFloatingWidgetView == null || mFloatingWidgetView.findViewById(R.id.collapse_view).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }


    /*  return status bar height on basis of device display metrics  */
    private int getStatusBarHeight() {
        return (int) Math.ceil(25 * getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }


    /*  Update Floating Widget view coordinates on Configuration change  */
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        getWindowManagerDefaultDisplay();

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) mFloatingWidgetView.getLayoutParams();

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {


            if (layoutParams.y + (mFloatingWidgetView.getHeight() + getStatusBarHeight()) > szWindow.y) {
                layoutParams.y = szWindow.y - (mFloatingWidgetView.getHeight() + getStatusBarHeight());
                mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatingWidgetView, layoutParams);
            }

            if (layoutParams.x != 0 && layoutParams.x < szWindow.x) {
                resetPosition(szWindow.x);
            }

        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

            if (layoutParams.x > szWindow.x) {
                resetPosition(szWindow.x);
            }

        }

    }

    /*  on Floating widget click show expanded view  */
    private void onFloatingWidgetClick() {
        if (isViewCollapsed()) {
            //When user clicks on the image view of the collapsed layout,
            //visibility of the collapsed layout will be changed to "View.GONE"
            //and expanded view will become visible.
            collapsedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            expandedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        /*  on destroy remove both view from window manager */

        if (mFloatingWidgetView != null)
            mWindowManager.removeView(mFloatingWidgetView);

        if (removeFloatingWidgetView != null)
            mWindowManager.removeView(removeFloatingWidgetView);

    }

}
```

Permissioncheck.java

```
 private void writeCalendarEvent()
    {

        Log.d(Utils.LogTag, "lst_StartService -> Utils.canDrawOverlays(Main.this): " + Utils.canDrawOverlays(Permissioncheck.this));
        if(Utils.canDrawOverlays(Permissioncheck.this))
        {
            checkPermission_Contact();
            startService();
        }
        else
        {
            requestPermission(OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE_CHATHEAD);
        }
    }

    public void startService()
    {
        boolean results = checkPermission_Contact();
        if (results)
        {
            Intent k = new Intent(context, Login.class);
            startActivity(k);
        }

    }

    private void needPermissionDialog(final int requestCode)
    {
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(Permissioncheck.this);
        builder.setMessage("You need to allow permission");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        requestPermission(requestCode);
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void requestPermission(int requestCode)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE_CHATHEAD)
        {
            if (!Utils.canDrawOverlays(Permissioncheck.this))
            {
                needPermissionDialog(requestCode);
            } else
            {
                startService();
            }
        }
    }
```

Help me to fix the problem.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867533/system-alert-window-permission-on-api-26-not-working-as-expected-permission-den

Answer (score 1):

add `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` 
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52059033/permission-denied-for-window-type-2002-in-android-studio)