# Android OREO, TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR on system app

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to make an app that its behavior was like cover app, where I can show clocks, answer or reject a call, control music and more.

*But I have problems with **Android Oreo**.*

In previous versions I could do it with the indicator `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR`, and with this indicator I could put my view above all the other views, including, on the view of the call.

But with Android Oreo I try to do the same with `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`.

It partially work, but It doesn´t work with phone screen, with this flag when a call is incoming the native call screen is on top of my app, and I dont want that.

I can put my app on priv_app folder. And I can have system permissions.

What can I do?

The error is,
[image: error]

the code is,

[image: code]

Comment: Hi Gustavo. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the code in the question, not as a link. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. But please do not use images in the future. It is difficult for someone to help if they cannot paste and run the code. Instead, just paste the text of the source code into the question. Once that is done, highlight all the code and press the "{}" icon to format it. Regards.

Comment: I have up-voted your question. Let us see if someone will help. 

But it looks like there is a good answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224452/android-unable-to-add-window-permission-denied-for-this-window-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224452/android-unable-to-add-window-permission-denied-for-this-window-type)