# Realy android dual display permission problem

Tags: android

I have Point of Service device 
this device has dual screen

When the target api is less than 22, 

It only worked if you had the permission .
but Problem occurs when target api is 22 or higher 
problem is permission denied for this window type

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Context context;
   DisplayManager mDisplayManager;
   DifferentDisplay mPresentation;
   DifferentDisplay2 mPresentation2;
   Display[]  displays;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

    } else{
        //this is not working
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW},0);
    }


    mDisplayManager =(DisplayManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
    displays = mDisplayManager.getDisplays();

    mPresentation = new DifferentDisplay(context,displays[1]);//displays[1] is the customer display)
    mPresentation.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    mPresentation.show();

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mPresentation2 = new DifferentDisplay2(context,displays[1]);//displays[1] is the customer display)
            mPresentation2.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            mPresentation2.show();


        }
    });

}
}
```

this is my logs

04-01 09:55:18.042 16389-16389/com.example.dualscreen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dualscreen, PID: 16389
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dualscreen/com.example.dualscreen.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@f70b45a -- permission denied for this window type
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2421)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5425)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:772)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
     Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@f70b45a -- permission denied for this window type
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:591)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
        at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:235)
        at com.example.dualscreen.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6266)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2374)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5425) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:772) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)

Comment: format your question properly (hint, `{}` button) and do not spam with irrelevant tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32224452/8809599

Answer (score 0):

```
 mPresentation.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
```

This way, you do not need permissions. but

```
mPresentation.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
```

Using it still causes problems Who has a better solution?