# How to fix WindowManagerBadtokenException in Service that doesn't have activity android?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-source, android-windowmanager

I have created an aosp where in service, it has window manager. I have declared window manager permission in manifest but I am still getting error that unable to add window.

```
public class BannerService extends Service {
private WindowManager mWinManager;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams mUpperBannerParams;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams mExpandSysMsgLayoutParam;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams mExpandLayoutParam;
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
 mWinManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
 mUpperBannerParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR);
        mUpperBannerParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        mUpperBannerParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
mUpperBannerParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
        mUpperBannerParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        mUpperBannerParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL;
View bannerBackView = layout_inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_banner_background, null);

        mExpandBannerWindowContainer = new FrameLayout(this) {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
                cancelResetExpandBanner(); // fail-safe: 
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            }
        };
        mWinManager.addView(mExpandBannerWindowContainer, mUpperBannerParams); //getting error at 813th line is this because windowmanager in 9. 

}
}
```

I even added

But I get error as

```
 12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service jp.advop.banner.application.BannerService: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@36c0149 -- permission denied for window type 2010
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3582)
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:200)
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1672)
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:917)                                                
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@36c0149 -- permission denied for window type 2010
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:822)
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at jp.advop.banner.application.BannerService.onCreate(BannerService.java:813)
12-13 05:28:55.218  1125  1125 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3570)
```

I even used foregroundService too.

```
  public class ServiceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        intent.setClass(context, BannerService.class);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                context.startForegroundService(intent);
            } else {
                context.startService(intent);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What Android version are you testing this on?

Comment: Android 9. In 6, it works. I am migrating the 6 Banner Service to android 9. When I run in 9, it throws the error.

Answer (score 2):

From Android 8 onwards, apps that use the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission can no longer use the `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` window type to display alert windows above other apps and system windows.

Instead, use a new window type called [`TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY).

Reference: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#cwt

Comment: So instead of WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR, I need to use TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY?

Comment: I am still getting same error. Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@913479c -- permission denied for window type 2010

Comment: Have you declared `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes I declared the permission.

Comment: Whether I need to use drawOverlay? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52988152/1921263 but I don't have activity to use.