# Widndow manager crashes in Samsung only

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-windowmanager

```
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@20c99f0 -- permission denied for this window type 2038
```

I have asked a question in Github. Please see and give me a solution
https://github.com/premnirmal/Magnet/issues/6#issuecomment-591894836

I am using this GitHub lib also, so I asked question over there

I have followed all the steps for WindowOverlay permission.

But why only Samsung devices getting crash in Android 9 and not in other devices?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/32233473/6280156

Comment: @Venky, I done same what those answers are saying, It is working fine in other devices. Also working in Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 and Samsung edge 6. But not working in those devices which are listed in the image